# Cannot download the tensorflow library

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

When I run:

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.15.0 tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0 stable_baselines gym box2d-py --user
```

I get an error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.15.0 (from versions: 2.2.0rc3, 2.2.0rc4, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0rc0, 2.3.0rc1, 2.3.0rc2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.4.0rc0, 2.4.0rc1, 2.4.0rc2, 2.4.0rc3, 2.4.0rc4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.5.0rc0, 2.5.0rc1, 2.5.0rc2, 2.5.0rc3, 2.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.15.0

Upon running the following commands:

```
!pip --version
!python --version
```

I get this:

pip 21.1.2 from /Users/yashbharti/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
Python 2.7.16

Answer (score 2):

The version of Tensorflow that you are trying to download is not compatible with python 3.8 (version of python in your pip installer).
In the future I recommend you to use a virtual env like anaconda, it makes way easier to manage all of the version of python and it's frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, there is no tensorflow release version that matches the one you provided.

The tensorflow docs suggest [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/installation#legacy_use_with_tensorflow_1)

Answer (score 0):

first, check whether you have installed python correctly by
(*python --version*)

then, check whether you have downloaded pip3 by
(*pip3 --version*)

then, type
(*pip3 install TensorFlow*)  in cmd

Comment: OP already has python and pip installed, or else he wouldn't be able to run `pip install` in the first place.